# Fazer Upload e visulizar PDF's Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Queria tirar uma dúvida, estou tentando fazer um upload de um arquivo PDF, no django, e eu queria saber se te como eu visualizar este pdf, tenho o seguinte código:

**models.py**

```
class Edital(models.Model):
    # ...

class DataFile(models.Model):
    Arquivo = models.FileField()

    def chage_view(self):
        return self.Arquivo

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Editais'

Numero = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length= 15) 
pro_reitoria = models.ForeignKey('Pro_reitoria', default="")
Arquivo = models.FileField(upload_to= "", default="")

def __str__(self):
    return self.Numero
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

no meu admin fica assim o arquivo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu clico no arquivo carregado aparece Page not Found(404)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço pra eu conseguir visualizar o PDF??
Agradeço quem puder me ajudar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que o único detalhe que esteja faltando, seja você habilitar o Django a servir os arquivos estáticos e de media, coisa que ele não faz por padrão. Para fazer isso, só fazer isso no seu `urls.py` do projeto:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# depois das suas definições de urls

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(
    settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, resolveu meu problema!!